# Getting 405 Method Not Allowed error when calling my Flask API

Tags: python, http, flask, backend

```
routes.py:
    
    def create_authentication_routes(api: Api): 
        api.add_resource(AuthenticationApi, '/register', endpoint='register')
```

```
auth_api.py:

   class AuthenticationApi(Resource):
        @staticmethod
        def register() -> Response
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": success}), 200)`
```

```
app.py:

    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)
        api = Api(app=app)create_authentication_routes(api)

    if name == "main":
        app = create_app()
        app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

When I make request via POST /register, I get 405 method not allowed error.

I know that I can get it to work with class definition like below:

```
class RegistrationApi(Resource):
    @static method 
    def get():
        ...
        ...
```

However, I am having trouble getting it to work with the Resource class definition above. Is there a way to do it this way?

Comment: I get the same result, 404 Not Found.

Comment: Sorry, I get 405 Method Not Allowed when I request /register.